# Should you use encrypted DNS before connecting to a VPN?

Tags: encryption, vpn, dns, anonymity

The ISP would still see the IP address of the VPN you're connecting to, but it would not be in plaintext compared to normal DNS from what I understand. Should one even bother or just let it be as it is?

Edit: I mean, instead of the ISP getting the domain name of the VPN server in plaintext, they'd only get the IP of the server if you use smart DNS like quad9 from what I understand. Is this correct?

Comment: *"The ISP would still see the IP address of the VPN you're connecting to, but it would not be in plaintext compared to normal DNS"* - in this sentence "it" refers to the IP address, which does not make sense for me since no DNS is involved when connecting to an IP address. Do you mean the domain name of the VPN provider instead?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The hostname can usually be obtained by doing a reverse DNS against the IP address. Can't fathom why you want to conceal that particular bit of information.